# How can I echo the value being used in document.write in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console

i am new to JS and still learning.  I googled before posting this but I couldn't find how to echo the value being used in document.write in console.

I have a page that has this:

```
document.write('<meta name="some:tags" content="' + thisLook + '">');
```

This is dynamically generating a value inside this meta tag and I need to just get the output of that value.

In Chrome console, how can I get the value in that meta tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.log(thisLook)` - this works for Firefox and recent IE's too.

Comment: Are you looking in the actual console?

Comment: @jeff the weird thing is that when i do the same thing for another url on the same site i keep getting "undefined" it only shows when I do a private window each time for each url.

Comment: That means the `thisLook` variable is not being set. I am assuming it is a global variable.